# Excel bearing calculations

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, coordinates

I want to find the compass bearing of to coordinates from a map:
[Map with example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTXga.jpg) *The middle Point is my location.*

I already know the distance between my points. But I don't find a formula for the bearing that fits in an Excel sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from here: https://www.igismap.com/formula-to-find-bearing-or-heading-angle-between-two-points-latitude-longitude/
You can calculate your direction in radians and then degrees using:

```
=DEGREES(ATAN2(x2-x1,y2-y1))
```

You can then use functions from here:
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/convert-number-in-deg-to-direction-text-n-nne.541185/
to allocate a map direction, this one appears best:

```
=CHOOSE(1+ROUND(A1/22.5,0),"N","NNE","NE","ENE","E","ESE","SE","SSE","S","SSW","SW","WSW","W","WNW","NW","NNW","N")
```

or you can combine the lot in one cell something like:

```
=ROUND(DEGREES(ATAN2(B2,B3)),2) & "° " & LOOKUP(MOD(DEGREES(ATAN2(B2,B3)),360),{0,22.5,45,67.5,90,112.5,135,157.5,180,202.5,225,247.5,270,292.5,315,337.5},{"N","NNE","NE","ENE","E","ESE","SE","SSE","S","SSW","SW","WSW","W","WNW","NW","NNW"})
```

where I have the X and Y calculations in B2 and B3.

It has been some time since I worked with coordinates so it may not be the correct terminology but you should be able to modify to suit.

Comment: Thank you it worked.